# the tuple argument in calendar.timegm function

Tags: python, python-3.x, time, calendar

```
>>> calendar.timegm((2012,8,10,7,10,20,None,None,1))
1326179420
>>> calendar.timegm((2012,8,10,7,10,20,None,None,0))
1326179420
>>> calendar.timegm((2012,8,10,7,10,20,None,None,-1))
1326179420
>>>
```

There are 9 elements in the tuple arugment in `calendar.timegm` ,the last one is daylight saving flag, why different value of flag get the same output? I think the results should be different.

Now if a us writer sign the time 2014,8,13, morning 9:30:00 in his article.
question1:
should we adjust the time to a tuple like (2014,8,13,8,30,00) to be the argument in calendar.timegm?
Daylight saving time is one clock faster than normal time.
It is (2014,8,13,8,30,00) or (2014,8,13,9,30,00) to be the argument in calendar.timegm ?

question2:
Tom and his computer located in USA,Peter and his computer located in CHINA,
will the result of calendar.timegm((2014,8,13,8,30,00) in Tom's console be the same in Peter's console?

> > > import calendar
> > >       calendar.timegm((2014,8,13,8,30,00))
> > >       1407918600

What number is yours located in USA?

Comment: Because it represents GMT, `calendar.timegm((2014,8,13,8,30,00))` will be the same regardless of location.

Comment: 1.the argument tuple for calendar.timegm must be GMT time.

Comment: 2.The us writer who lived in newyork ,sign the time  2014,8,13, morning 9:30:00 according to his watch ,we change it into normal time(none daylight saving time) as (2014,8,13,8,30,00) and again change it into GMT time as  (2014,8,13,3,30,00) because newyork is in -0500 timezone.

Comment: 3.the argument tuple is  (2014,8,13,3,30,00) for the example,and calendar.timegm((2014,8,13,3,30,00))=1407900600 is equal for anywhere in the world.

Comment: all the point1,point2,point3 are right?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think that daylight savings time can actually be applied to GMT, hence the dst flag would have no meaning anyway.

Comment: Now if a us writer sign the time 2014,8,13, morning 9:30:00 in his article,how can we write the tuple as argment in the function calendar.timegm ,us is in the daylight saving time ,it matter.

Comment: Wouldn't you set the article time to that of your server? Otherwise, you have all 6 required fields, so either the writer needs to supply 24 hour time, or you need to interpret "morning" as AM and adjust the hour accordingly (in this case, no adjustment is required).

Comment: should i adjust the time to a tuple like (2014,8,13,8,30,00) to be the argument in calendar.timegm?Daylight saving time is one clock faster than normal time,am i right?

Comment: Why don't you just store the time that the article was submitted in UTC, using the time on your server (which you can keep properly synchronised)? Relying on your users to manually enter a time, or extracting it via javascript are options, but these are less reliable.

Comment: If i manually change the time ,it is  (2014,8,13,8,30,00)  not  (2014,8,13,9,30,00) that will be put into calendar.timegm,and the computer which to make the operation must be in usa too?

Comment: How will you know what the dst offset is, or even whether dst applies for the given date? Clock goes _forward_ during dst  but it can be 1 hour, 0.5 hours, 45 mins depending on the timezone and the rules that apply at the time.

Comment: dear mhawke,the result of calendar.timegm((2014,8,13,8,30,00)) is 1407918600 ,what is yours?

Comment: Well, of course, it's the same - 1407918600. It is GMT so it will be the same everywhere.